# Is $\varphi: \operatorname{Spec}A_{\mathfrak o}\to \operatorname{Spec}A$ injective and open on the underlying topological spaces?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $A$ be a commutative ring with unity, $\mathfrak p$ a prime ideal of $A$, then is $\varphi: \operatorname{Spec}A_{\mathfrak p}\to \operatorname{Spec}A$ induced by the canonical homomorphism $A\to A_{\mathfrak p}$ injective and open on the underlying topological spaces?

Comment: It is injective. It is not open, as its image is the set of points specializing to $\mathfrak{p}$ (take for instance $\mathbb{Z}$).

Comment: This map on spectra is injective, which boils down to some calculations involving localization theory of commutative rings. Even more is true. Consider a multiplicative set $S\subseteq A$ and the canonical map $A\rightarrow S^{-1}A$, then $$\mathrm{Spec}\,S^{-1}A\rightarrow \mathrm{Spec}\,A$$
is injective. 

Now consider the canonical map $A\rightarrow A_{\mathfrak{p}}$. The image of this map in $\mathrm{Spec}\, A$ consists of 

$$\{\mathfrak{q}\in \mathrm{Spec}\,A\,|\,\mathfrak{q}\subseteq \mathfrak{p}\}$$

but this rarely is an open set. In very special cases it is open.

Comment: At least one of you should turn your comments in to an answer, please :)